# Instance of 'Vouch' has no 'user' member

Tags: python, discord.py

Both Codes have the same error. "Instance of 'Vouch' has no 'user' member". It is a vouch bot for discord.py

```
    @check(is_bot_owner)
    async def name(self, ctx, *, new_name: str):
        """Vouch Bot"""
        await self.user.edit(username=new_name)
        await ctx.send(no_ping("Changed name to {}.".format(new_name)))

@command()
    @check(is_bot_owner)
    async def avatar(self, ctx):
        """Insert The Bot Avatar Here"""
        att = ctx.message.attachments
        if len(att) == 1:
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                async with session.get(att[0].proxy_url) as resp:
                    avatar = await resp.read()
                    await self.user.edit(avatar=avatar)
                    await ctx.send("Avatar changed.")
```

Comment: A full error output would be good to see where exactly the error is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `self.bot.user` (or `self.client.user`, depends how you named it) not `self.user`

```py
await self.bot.user.edit(...) # Or self.client.user.edit
```

Also instead of creating a new session everytime the command `avatar` is been invoked, you can simply download the image with `Attachment.read`

```py
att = ctx.message.attachments
if len(att) == 1:
    f = await att[0].read()
    await self.bot.user.edit(avatar=f) # Or self.client.user.edit
```

Also if you're going to mess with `aiohttp` it's a bad idea to create a new session every time a command is called, you should have only ONE session open at all times that performs the requests altogether.